# Django admin cache m2m relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-cache, django-caching, django-cache-machine

I have two models:

**models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Company(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City, null=True, blank = True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('title',)
    filter_horizontal = ('cities',)
```

It is about 23000 cities in the database.

When i edit the Company detail in Admin it loads forever!!! **Just accessing admin/myapp/company/12/ takes 2-3 minutes - this is horrible.**

How can i speed up things and cache City model queryset?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("cities",)
```

Answer (score 1):

23000 is actually "nothing" for a database.

First, you need to identify the "culprit" of a slowdown, which query is slow. This is where [`django-debug-toolbar`](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) would help a lot. Then, you can run the queries manually with `EXPLAIN` and see what can be improved - for example, adding indexes could help.

Also, consider using [`django-cache-machine`](http://cache-machine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [`johnny-cache`](https://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/) packages.

Also see:

- [Tweaks for making django admin faster](http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2012/01/19/tweaks-for-making-django-admin-faster/)